# Conversão de uma sub-consulta de Data em Caracter no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

eu tenho uma sub-consulta retornando datas desta forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DT_EMISSAO_NF FROM DANFE ORDER BY DT_EMISSAO_NF DESC
```

E, partindo desta consulta, eu preciso que todas as datas retornadas sejam convertidas em caracter nesse padrão 'DD/MM/YYY'

- Se eu fizer a conversão em uma única consulta, a ordenação classifica todos os númerais dos dias, depois do mês, e então depois do ano, e no caso preciso que me retornem como se fosse a data mesmo, os dias mais atuais retornando  primeiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só usar o `TO_CHAR` passando o formato que deseja.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DT_EMISSAO_NF, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss') 
FROM DANFE ORDER BY DT_EMISSAO_NF DESC
```

Para usar com o Distinct faça um sub select, assim:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(QRY.DT_CADASTRO, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss') FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT DT_CADASTRO FROM PROJETO ORDER BY DT_CADASTRO DESC
) QRY;
```

Mais informações [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm).

Comment: "ORA-01791: não é uma expressão de SELECT"

Comment: Qual a versão do seu oracle?

Comment: Editei a resposta. Dê uma olhada.

Comment: Sucesso :) Funcionou. Muito obrigado.